# In safari of ios, when there is a "onclick" inline a child, and a "onmouseover" inline a parent, why mouseover event fired when click the child?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

In safari of ios, when there is a "onclick" inline a child element, and a "onmouseover" inline a parent element. When touch the child, I want the click event be fired, but first the mouseover event be fired.

```
<span onmouseover='dosomething1()'>
    <ul>
        <li onclick='dosomething2()'></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

I open this html in safari in iPhone, when I click/touch the li element, dosomething1 executed, and I click/touch the li element again, dosomething2 executed. What can I do to make sure only dosomething2 execute when I click the li element?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 0):

Because the `mouseover` event *bubbles* from the child to the parent, and for maximum compatibility, mobile browsers fire a `mouseover` event when the finger position changes.

If you use proper event handling, or pass the `event` object into `dosomething1`, `dosomething1` can look at `event.target` to see whether the target of the `mousemove` was the `span` or a descendant element and take appropriate action (or appropriately take no action).

Alternately, you can hook `mouseover` on (say) the `ul` and stop the event from bubbling ("propagating") to its ancestors.

Example of using proper event handling and doing the check in the `mousemove` handler:

```js
document.getElementById("the-span").addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        dosomething1();
    }
});
document.getElementById("the-li").addEventListener("click", dosomething2);

function dosomething1() {
    console.log("mousemove on the span");
}

function dosomething2() {
    console.log("click on the li");
}
```

```html
<span id="the-span">
    <ul>
        <li id="the-li">Text</li>
    </ul>
    text in span outside the li
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I have another question: is it possible to make the "mouseover" and "click" event both be fired when click/touch the li element inside the span?

Comment: @宣翔宇: I thought that was what was happening now.

Comment: No, as for now, if I touch the li element only once, the "mouseover" is fired, and "click" is not. I must touch the li twice and the "click" could be fired.

Comment: @宣翔宇: No idea what that is, I would normally expect a click on a single touch.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my code, I will check it. Thank you!

Comment: about the not fired click event on first touch, this might be helpful: http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html